# Abrir Terminal com Swift

Tags: swift, osx

Tem como eu pedir para meu programa gráfico abrir uma janela terminal passando uns comandos com parâmetros? Estou usando Swift para OS X, Grato.

Comment: A sua dificuldade é sobre qual o comando que abre o terminal ou o conjunto inteiro?

Comment: Seria qual comando que abre o terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para abrir qualquer aplicativo você pode utilizar o comando [**open**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html). O argumento **-b** permite você identificar o aplicativo através do seu pacote, então para abrir o terminal você pode fazer assim:

```
open -b com.apple.terminal
```

Agora, se após isso você quer executar algum script, acredito (e talvez seja a melhor opção) será preciso criar um arquivo executável e então incluir no comando acima. Por exemplo, se você possui um arquivo **script.sh**, ficaria assim:

```
open -b com.apple.terminal script.sh
```

Lembrando que este arquivo deve ter as permissões necessárias para ser executado.